# Avast premium security firewall block local kafka connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, antivirus

I have installed Avast premium security and its firewall block my Spring boot application to connect to my local kafka (localhost:9092). Added cmd.exe, java.exe to firewall whitelist but no luck. Any solution? Thank you

```
Oracle JDK 11
Kafka 2.13
Spring boot 3.9
```

PS: Workaround solution: disable Avast (or its firewall)

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow incoming and outgoing communications in your applications, you must add your application to the [list of allowed apps](https://support.avast.com/en-ph/article/use-antivirus-blocked-allowed-apps/#pc) in Avast and [create application rules](https://support.avast.com/en-us/article/antivirus-firewall-application-rules/#pc).

Add to the list of allowed apps:

1. Open Avast UI goto Menu>Settings
2. Select General>Blocked & Allowed Apps
3. Click Allow app
4. You can add the app from the list or Select app manually
5. Choose the features that will allow the selected app then click Add

Avast features will now allow the application you added from the list but you can remove it anytime.

Create an application rule:

1. Open Avast UI goto Protection>Firewall
2. Click the settings button on the top right corner and a new window will appear
3. Choose Protection and click "View Firewall Rules"
4. On the Rule list choose Application Rules tab, click More then "Allow new app"
5. Choose the application from the list of allowed apps

You may now configure the application rules by adding the specific ports you want to allow and the ports that your application is using. Edit the existing rules or add new rules.